# javascript PeriodicalExecuter crashing into user's submit (POST)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, listener, dom-events

When I look at logs with the Charles proxy, I see that the user's submit (POST) doesn't always contain all the form data. Sometimes it is missing the bottom third of the form data, apparently when the AJAX call in the `PeriodicalExecuter` fires. I'm not absolutely sure about this. Here's roughly how the page script looks:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  ...
  new PeriodicalExecuter(function(pe) {msgEntryRqst(host_URL, web_sid, pageType, recordNbr);}, delaySecs);
  ...
}

function msgEntryRqst(host_URL, web_sid, pageType, recordNbr) {
    ...
    new Ajax.Request('/'+host_URL, {
    method: 'get', 
    parameters: {c: 'AJAX_request', ajtype: 'instantMessage', sid: web_sid, pagetype: pageType, record: recordNbr, rnd: Math.random()},
    onSuccess: function(response) { 
        if(response.responseText.length>0) {
                         ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do, for example, `DOCUMENT.observe('click', 'myHandler')`, perhaps within the `"dom:loaded"` section, to set a flag when the user has clicked on a save button or navigation tab, to skip one cycle of the AJAX command and thereby not truncate the user's POST?